# C# Visual Studio Second Form Displaying Blank Page

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a website in Visual Studio with C# and forms. I want to make it so after a user puts their information into the first form and submits it that form will close and the new one will take its place. The button works for everything except when the new form displays it's the completely blank default form rather than the one I created. I added all the relevant code down below. Thank you for any advice you can offer.

Form1:

```
    private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of the CodeUI form and show it
        CodeUI form2 = new CodeUI();
        form2.Show();

       // Close the old form
       // this.Close();
    }
```

Form2 (CodeUI):

```
public partial class CodeUI : Form
{
    public CodeUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += CodeUILoadHandler; // Rename the event handler
    }
```

I've made sure that the name isn't misspelled in the code. Creating and changing the event handler for this. I've tried learning how to just replace everything that is on the current form with the new information when the button is clicked but I'm very inexperienced with C# so I don't know the best way to do that either.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough details to write an answer. See [ask]. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @spmecode have a look at this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to do in the CodUI form. Could you please send some screenshots of forms 1 and 2? Also, the InitializeComponent code of the CodeUI would be helpful.